# SQL Adding quantity of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I need to compute the sum of a column (B) in another column (C), but adding the next value and changing taking into account another column criteria (A), something like this:

[image]

Is this possible with a simple SELECT?

Comment: Is it possible? Probably. If you provide a clear description of the logic to be used rather than some unclear "like this" and "taking into account another column" phrases, someone might be able to help.

Comment: You want to get a running total of column B in column C for each distinct value in column A, correct? If so: `=SUMIF(A$1:A1,A1, $B$1:$B$8)` and copy down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, the window function `sum() over()` should do the trick.

Note the `order by ColB`  ... This is just a placeholder, I suspect you have another column which would have the proper sequence

**Example**

```
Select ColA
      ,ColB
      ,ColC = sum(ColB) over (partition by ColA order by ColB rows unbounded preceding )
 From  YourTable
```

Comment: John, your solution almost work except in a certain case. When COLB repeats, COLC has always the same result, the total sum. For example, imagine COLB has 20, 40, 40 values, then COLC shows 20, 100, 100, when it should be: 20, 60, 100

Comment: @Mazinger Just added tje rows unbounded preceding ...  As Charilieface suggested.

Comment: @Mazinger Here is a working example  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=193cde04d266f9ad5a1eeee42ae18212

Comment: Now it totally works! That last tip do the trick.